# How replayable is Pandemic Legacy? (Is the game still playable after you have completed it)

Tags: pandemic-legacy

So my understanding is that Pandemic Legacy has a story arc of 12-24 games, at which point the game is complete.

My question is - according to the design of the game - is the game still playable as a 'non-story' game, scars and all, once this is complete?

ie. *I'm not asking about whether I can play the twelve month story through again*

If not - what are people meant to do with their sets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would it be possible to play through Pandemic Legacy more than once?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/30282/would-it-be-possible-to-play-through-pandemic-legacy-more-than-once)

Comment: That is not a duplicate as this is asking if it can be played a non story game and the duplicate is asking if you can play through the story again.

Comment: It's not more replayable than a good meal is reeatable.

Comment: "what are people meant to do with their sets?" we kept ours as a memento. Lots of fond memories associated with that set.

Answer (score 13):

It is not intended to be replayable.

Depending on what options you choose during the campaign, certain components are intended to be physically destroyed. You could choose to just set things aside instead of destroying them; though that does take away some of the thematic fun. And then you would just have to ignore any stickers that were put on the board during play if you wanted to play regular Pandemic after.

You can either throw it out or keep it as a souvenir.  As a matter of pure opinion; it is well worth it even though you can’t keep playing it after; those 12-24 games are worth the cost!

Comment: Some Legacy games are designed so that at the end of the campaign you have your own unique version of the game that can be played over and over again (I believe Charterstone and Machi Koro Legacy both fall into that group). That said, PL:S1 is *not* one of those games.

Comment: You could potentially re-play the "December" game over and over again, but that's certainly not the intent of the design and for gameplay-related reasons it may not be fantastic (without spoiling too much, the design did not aim to give you something particularly playable or interesting at the end of the campaign, depending on how certain events played out throughout the campaign).

Comment: You could, in theory, still play the base game by ignoring all the stickers on the board and cards.  I'm only up to October, but other than character destruction, I've only encountered one thing that permanently destroys a base game part, and it's optional.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can use the board, cards, and components to play it as the original Pandemic game. After playing.